# How to get the prev and next elements of a particular class which are not siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is my code :

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">
        <div class="course_video_heading"><span class="minus"></span> Introduction <div class="course_duration" align="right">1m 21s</div></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="course_video viewed">
                Welcome <div class="course_duration" align="right">1m 21s</div>
            </li>
            <li class="course_video viewed">
                I need to select this <div class="course_duration" align="right">1m 21s</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="course_video_heading"><span class="plus"></span> Warm up <div class="course_duration" align="right">1h 15m</div></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="course_video viewed current">
                Roll down <div class="course_duration" align="right">57s</div>
            </li>
            <li class="course_video">
                Roll down with demi pointe variation <div class="course_duration" align="right">57s</div>
            </li>
            <li class="course_video" data-file="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" data-image="http://content.bitsontherun.com/thumbs/nPripu9l-480.jpg">
                Side roll down <div class="course_duration" align="right">57s</div>
            </li>
            <li class="course_video">
                Side roll down variation with contraction <div class="course_duration" align="right">57s</div>
            </li>
            <li class="course_video">
                Class exercise <div class="course_duration" align="right">57s</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="course_video_heading"><span class="plus"></span> Brushes <div class="course_duration" align="right">1h 5m</div></div>
        <ul>
            <li class="course_video">
                Welcome <div class="course_duration" align="right">1m 21s</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My requirement : There is a element, `<li class="course_video viewed current">`, I need the previous `li` which has `course_video` class. In this case it would be :

```
<li class="course_video viewed">
    I need to select this <div class="course_duration" align="right">1m 21s</div>
</li>
```

What have I tried :

```
$(".current").prev(".course_video")
```

This is not working as it is in different `li`

Note : It is not the duplicate of following questions :)

[jQuery to find nearest Div of Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862109/jquery-to-find-nearest-div-of-parent)

[Getting next closest select element with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050445/getting-next-closest-select-element-with-jquery)

[jquery find closest previous sibling with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310270/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-with-class)

Comment: You can try to get all elements by class "course_video", then find among them elements with class "current", like here http://jsfiddle.net/0k541m6w/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : read the index of `current` li and if it is `0` then find the previous `li` of its parent `li` and then find the `course_video`. And if index is not `0`, then find previous `li` using `prev()`

```
var index = $(".current").index();
if(index==0)
{
    var previousLi = $(".current").closest('li').prev('li').find("li.course_video:last");
}
else
{
  var previousLi = $(".current").prev(".course_video");
}
```

Comment: This looks fine let me try this, But I am expecting a solution with out any conditions

Answer (score 1):

```
var vindex;
$().ready(function () {
    $("li .course_video").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
            vindex = index;
        }
    });
    $("li .course_video").each(function (index) {
        if (index == vindex - 1) {
           alert($(this)[0].outerHTML);
        }
    });
});
```

this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.current').parents('li').prev().find('li:last')
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6t2zmgcc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a function that checks the index of the item: if the index is 0 then you'll select the last `li` in the previous `ul`.

```
Element.prototype.previousLi = function() {
    var i = $(this).index(),
        n = this.parentElement.previousSibling.children.length;

    if (i) return this.parentElement.children[i-1];
    else return this.parentElement.previousSibling.children[n-1];
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var el = $(".course_video.viewed.current")[0];
var previous = el.previousLi();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code , it will give you the desired result :

```
   <script>
    var currentLI = $("li.current");

    prevLi=$(currentLI).parent('ul').parent('li').prev('li').find('li.viewed:last');

    alert($(prevLi).html());
    </script>
```